# How to encode UTF-8 for XML document in Java

Tags: java, excel, utf-8

I have a java program that read some stuff out of an excel sheet and creates XML.

Long story short I need the string contained within the XML to only contain valid XML characters and to properly encode and characters that need to be encoded.

**Question: How can I encode these characters in java before writing to the file?**

Thanks!

Note: These are characters such as: “ `(&#x201C;)` and ” `(&#x201D;)` and other similar characters.

Comment: The problem isn't with Java, which handles UTF just fine.  Excel is the weak link in your chain and is probably inserting canted quotes instead of normal vertical quotes and em-dash instead of dash and so forth.  Fix your spreadsheet.

Comment: Well I'm fine if there is a setting in excel that make it use UTF, I have enough control over the excel sheet to make the users change the format. However, if I can't enforce that in excel, I would like to translate it when I read it into the java program.

Comment: How do you input the excel sheet into Java (as CSV) file? For each stream in Java (input and output), you need proper encoding, then Java does the rest for you.

Comment: I'm using `org.apache.poi` I just say: `InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("forms.xls"); Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);`

Comment: How do you validate errors? can you post some characters you think are incorrect against some expected ones? I am asking this because many times in case of if editors/consoles which supports only ASCII, unicode characters are displayed as "?", which creates confusion even having right solution.

Comment: So, for example, the quotes are different. It seems maybe they copy and pasted into excel from another program. The quotes show up as `“` as opposed to `"` The former of which is not `UTF-8`

Comment: If you can save Excel as `.xlsx` you have zipped XML, where internally the character encoding is well-defined. Otherwise you have to assume that the Excel actually is in `windows-1252` or so.

Comment: OK, well if I assume that it is in `windows-1252`, can I convert it in my java program to `UTF-8`?

Comment: @ All - I updated the title of the question and the question description to better reflect what I'm looking for and so that this question is helpful for anyone else looking to do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand your question you want to write XML in UTF-8 format, to write a file in UTF-8 following is kind of standard way in Java using `OutputStreamWriter`:

```
File f = new File("test.xml");
BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(f), "UTF-8"));
wr.write("xml text here");
```

UTF-8 is a variable width encoding which can represent every character Unicode character set, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark#Smart_quotes.

Further in your case seems like you want to convert  “ to " and hoping that during UTF-8 conversion this would be handled (I might be wrong but this is what I perceived from your response).  Are you saying that in XSL have " character but XML has “ ? If so then its a different problem then what's being discussed.

Edit: Just to clarify, I don't see any problem if XSL has “ and written XML also has same character as far as UTF-8 encoding is concerned.

Following XML is a valid XML containing Unicode characters:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<summary>This is a summary, text may contain &#x201C;Unicode&#x201D; characters</summary>
</root>
```

Open in any browser, if the charset is supported XML would be rendered correctly otherwise in case of non-XML complaint characters following error would be thrown (at least in Chrome, might depend upon browser):

> CharRef: invalid decimal value

For ranges of valid charset in XML you can refer: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets

> Char     ::=      #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] |
>   [#x10000-#x10FFFF]
>   /* any Unicode character, excluding the surrogate blocks, FFFE, and FFFF. */

For non-compliant XML charset refer: http://www.w3.org/TR/unicode-xml/#Charlist

Similar to writing <,>," in an XML as these needs to be written as &lt,&gt,&quot, `Unicode` characters needs to be written in following way: &#xNNNN; where NNNN is Unicode hexadecimal number. Refer above sample XML.

So while programatically writing XML, you need to handle such characters explicitly as when you encounter such characters convert it into &#x form.

Comment: This is kinda what I'm doing, but it seems the characters in the excel document are not conforming to UTF-8 or at some point my InputStream is not reading them in as UTF-8

Comment: When the `Workbook` stuff properly handles encoding, which I assume, as Microsoft formats usually use Unicode internally, then properly specifying the output encoding should really be enough.

Comment: When I write the file out, I just say `File fileOut = new File("name.xml"); FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileOut); fileWriter.write(output);` where can i specify the encoding?

Comment: @SO - damn scroll bars! now I see your specification of UTF-8 at the end of your second java statement. I'll try that.

Comment: @harsh - I tried that and I'm still getting `“` on the output

Comment: @harsh - per your update - I think thats pretty much what I am saying. I try to open the XML in XMLSPY (which expect a Unicode UTF-8 format) and it's saying the quote is an invalid character. Are you saying both of these quotes are valid UTF-8 characters?

Comment: @kralco626 edited answer with some additional details, does that work? Can you check if modifing your XML replacing unicode quotation charater with &#x201C and &#x201D works in XMLSYP too? I think it would..

Comment: @harsh - I have to wait until my co-worker gets in, I don't actually have an XMLSPY license, however I tried your above xml in chrome and it worked, I replaced your encoding with the actual quote marks and it did throw the error. Your code also works in IE, of course when I put in the invalid characters IE just shows absolutely nothing... no error... gotta love IE.

Comment: @harsh - So, now that you have helped me correctly define my question, how do I, in java, identify these characters that need to be encoded before being put into an XML document (I'm going to update the question and the title)

Comment: @kralco626 this will depend upon how are you creating XML file? are you using DOM, SAX etc or just dumping inmemory string (containing xml data) into a file?

Comment: @harsh - I am just dumping an in-memory string into a file. I use XMLBeans to generate the XML, but I don't think that's relevant because it just gives me an in-memory string in java that I then write to a file.

Comment: @kralco626 You need to find out if its possible to alter contents while writing XML using XMLBeans. Checkout following example of XMLBeans how XML can be altered character by character: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/xmlbeans/trunk/samples/MixedContent/src/org/apache/xmlbeans/samples/cursor/MixedContent.java

Comment: @harsh - I'll take a look. But I'm thinking that given a in-memory string, there must be a library build into java or external, that can look through the string and encode it properly for XML.

Comment: @kralco626 one hack could be just to use `String.replaceAll` functionality to replace desired characters with &#x notations say something like : xmlString.replaceAll("“", "&#x201C")

Comment: @harsh - So idk whats going on now. Now when I try, chrome is accepting the quote directly in the xml, without using the encoding and it's not throwing an error

Answer (score -1):

Whenever reading a file or writing a file, be sure to define the encoding and use UTF-8. Be careful, because all this methods do also exist without encoding string and in this case, the OS default encoding is used.

E. g. use

`InputStreamReader myReader=InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF-8");`

instead of the constructor without carset name.

Comment: A XLS very unlikely is "UTF-8", but binary.